# solving Langevins dimensionless stochastic differential equation where the stochastic force varies as Sqrt(tao) in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, stochastic-process

i need help with solving Langevins dimensionless stochastic differential equation  where the stochastic force varies as Sqrt(tao) in mathematica.

Comment: Is this your process? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/203853/36633

Comment: thats not how this works. show the code you need help with.